# How to add additional text to the ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs

There is an HTML, which converts and displays the text in a container `div` by filters:

```
 <div ng-bind-html="message.message | hrefConvert | rawHtml | test"></div>
```

How I can add another object `message.file` in `ng-bind-html`, that to process by filter `test` and return additional text in `div` element?

Comment: Perhaps you could consider something like `<div><span ng-bind-html="something"></span> <span>something else</span></div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="message.message + message.file | hrefConvert | rawHtml | test"></div>
```

UPDATE:

I don't know the structure of the `message.file` and the filter `test` but you could prepare a function `convertArrayToSrting` in your controller to convert the array to string:

```
$scope.convertArrayToSrting = function(fileArray){
  var itemsConverted = [];
  angular.forEach(fileArray, function(item){
    this.push(item);
  }, itemsConverted);
  return itemsConverted.join();
}
<div ng-bind-html="message.message + convertArrayToSrting(message.file) | hrefConvert | rawHtml | test"></div>
```

Or.. You can use the filter `test` in you controller to filter each element

```
$scope.convertArrayToSrting = function(){
  var itemsConverted = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.message.file, function(item){
    this.push($filter('test')(item));
  }, itemsConverted);
  return itemsConverted.join();
}

<div ng-bind-html="message.message + convertArrayToSrting() | hrefConvert | rawHtml"></div>
```

**For a better answer you could show the code of your filter `test` and the object `message.file`**

Comment: `message.file` is not string. It is array that i need prepatre with test and return from array elements (string)

Comment: Thanks, but how instead `$scope.message.file` in  `angular.forEach($scope.message.file, function(item){}` to submit array from template? You have tried `convertArrayToSrting(message.file)` but in function param is null

Comment: And what is structure of filter `test`?